# Call python class on java (Android)

Tags: java, android, python, eclipse

I want use a python class in my android project, this class dont use external libs etc.. its pure text processing in python. I tried port this to java, but I dont know python language enought to do this (lambda returns, and more definitions).

I read about jython, but I dont understand the idea yet. I have pydev installed on my eclipse, but I am stucked in this.

I know I can create a pydev (jython) project, but I want only create an object of my python class and use their methods. Its possible a more easy or fast way to make this withouth use jython?

Answer (score 1):

Sure just put the python script in your assets, make it available and execute it with a java system call! Here is a link that shows how to run a python script on Android: https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/RunPythonFromShell

Comment: I dont understand the use described in tutorial, I will give a try to this answer :)